# Interrupted Laser propulsion and relativity

Tags: special-relativity, laser, space-travel

I have seen concerns that in order for a laser sail ship to work, the laser on Earth has to continue operating for centuries, which there is no gurantee of.

If the laser stopped operating after 300 years on Earth, 300 lightyears later, the ship would stop receiving the beam. But from the ship's perspective, much less than 600 years have passed, and the Earth's time has been moving slower than theirs, so how can the ship stop reciving the beam from Earth, when from their perspective, the beam won't be turned off until some point centuries or millenia in the future. How can the ship stop receiving the laser before it is turned off? Does that mean the relativistic ship can never stop receiving the laser from Earth?

However, by that logic, at some point they'd stop receiving the laser from Earth, as it would be photons that haven't been sent yet, and won't be for centuries or millenia to come

Comment: I'm not seeing where the confusion is. The sail ship will always travel slower than light, so regardless of when the laser stops on Earth, the ship will stop receiving the laser beam at some point after that.

Answer (score 0):

In the Earth's frame, the ship will loose power after 300 plus D/c years, where D is whatever distance the ship had reached in the Earth's frame when the beam vanished. D will depend upon the energy of the laser, the efficiency of the sail and the mass of the ship. In the Earth's frame the overall time will be less than 600 years. In the ship's frame the time will seem more than 300 years but less than the elapsed time on Earth- the ship will see the frequency of the beam red-shifted owing to the Doppler effect, and will see the duration of the beam lengthened proportionally.

Comment: Would the ship ever see the laser stop?

Comment: Yes. Didn't you understand the last sentence of my answer? It will see the laser stop after a time that is 300 years multiplied by a factor that takes account of the Doppler effect averaged over the length of the journey.

Comment: So even though the ship is time dilated, they will see the laser stop after more than 300 years of their own time? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: What's confusing me is that at say, 1 g acceleration, 600 years is dilated to 12.47 years on the ship, so I was thinking if the laser gets turned off after 300 years, the ship stops receiving it after 600 years, which would only be 12.47 on the ship, which would be long before the laser was turned off on Earth from the ship's perspective. But from your answer, I'm getting that it would take 600 years ship time to notice the laser stopping.

Comment: Ben, time dilation by itself is only part of the picture (and a misleading part IMHO). You need to take into account the relativity of simultaneity. To take your example, in the Earth's frame, 'now' on Earth after 600 years corresponds to a position the ship reaches after 12.47 years in its frame. But that's not true in the ship's frame. If I get the chance, I will edit my answer to explain it further.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you found the time to elaborate on your answer? From what I understand, you're saying the ship would still receive the beam, but it would be red shifted?